# Right parameter setting to ignore data loss on msdeploy with dbDacFx Provider

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, msdeploy

I'm using msdeploy to synchronize the DB, but the script is always being cancelled due to data loss, even though I explicitly set it up to ignore it. What am I doing wrong?

```
msdeploy -Verb:Sync -Source:dbDacFx="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DevelopmentDB;Integrated Security=True;",BlockOnPossibleDataLoss="False" -Dest:dbDacFx="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=ProductionDB;Integrated Security=True;"
```

This is the final result of the script:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to place that parameter on the destination not the source:

```
msdeploy -Verb:Sync -Source:dbDacFx="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DevelopmentDB;Integrated Security=True;" -Dest:dbDacFx="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=ProductionDB;Integrated Security=True;",BlockOnPossibleDataLoss="False"
```

More details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550081%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @DavidMartin, I also had a different issue. Even though I set up IncludeData=false it was not working, but that because this setting is for the source not the destination.

Comment: This answer doesn't add up for me. When I specify the BlockOnPossibleDataLoss setting as you've described, I get this error "Provider 'dbDacFx' does not support setting 'BlockOnPossibleDataLoss'". The link you've included sends me to the documentation for the dbSqlPackage  provider, not dbDacFx. Was your answer tested and known to be working?